# pandas: Calculate percentile by row and gracefully handle non-unique values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with about 1000 rows and a column called `calc_value`. About 10% of the `calc_value` values are 0.

I want to assign a percentile to each row in the dataframe based on `calc_value`. However, using `qcut` gives me an error due to non-unique bin edges:

```
df['percentile'] = pd.qcut(df.calc_value, 100, labels=False)
```

It throws this error:

```
 ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
    0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.00182298,
    0.0030689 ,  0.00394358,  0.00479595,  0.00547278,  0.0060241 ,
    0.0066023 ,  0.00712708,  0.00760456,  0.00816327,  0.00862069,
    0.00917431,  0.00959605,  0.01010101,  0.01058201,  0.01094173,
    0.01136364,  0.01185771,  0.01230635,  0.01282051,  0.01324503,
    0.01369863,  0.0140051 ,  0.01447252,  0.01489758,  0.01528912,
    0.01569299,  0.01612903,  0.01657785,  0.01699717,  0.01750547,
    0.017924  ,  0.01840491,  0.01889004,  0.0193326 ,  0.01984022,
    0.0202292 ,  0.02076186,  0.02118433,  0.02173913,  0.02217742,
    0.02265831,  0.0231333 ,  0.02369503,  0.02422837,  0.02482127,
    0.02551955,  0.0260492 ,  0.02659574,  0.02714932,  0.0276922 ,
    0.02816901,  0.02882712,  0.02941176,  0.03020364,  0.0308642 ,
    0.03141361,  0.03209368,  0.03278689,  0.03349899,  0.03433476,
    0.03508136,  0.03571429,  0.03645665,  0.03703704,  0.03768171,
    0.03852266,  0.0392761 ,  0.04021883,  0.04130278,  0.04222222,
    0.04316547,  0.04416658,  0.04528395,  0.04630852,  0.04761905,
    0.04908678,  0.05062638,  0.05230894,  0.05421013,  0.05604617,
    0.05833204,  0.06024096,  0.06314209,  0.06598985,  0.06975211,
    0.07406687,  0.08098836,  0.08905262,  0.10144029,  0.12169944,
    0.48      ])
```

I don't care if the bin edges aren't unique, I would like to proceed and assign an equal percentile of `0` to each row with a zero value. Then continue from there, with the next percentile being `10` in this case.

How can I ignore this error and continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) does exactly what you want, including good control about tie breaks

> **method** : str, optional
>   The method used to assign ranks to tied elements. The options are ‘average’, ‘min’, ‘max’, ‘dense’ and ‘ordinal’.

E.g.,

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

>>> rankdata([0, 2, 3, 2], method='min')
array([ 1.,  2.,  4.,  2.])
```

So, in your case, you could use

```
from scipy.stats import rankdata

df['percentile'] = rankdata(df.calc_value.values, method=<whatever you want>) / len(df)
```

(Note how we divide by the length of the DataFrame).

Comment: Yes, thank you! I ended up subtracting 1 from the rank to get the percentiles I wanted. This worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

i believe pd.qcut() will need an interger number as second arg such that the number of data rows / int is also an int. so you will either have to add empty rows to delete them later or find the closest int through:

```
div = 100
while True:
    if not 968%div:
        break
    else:
        div -= 1
print div
```