# pandas: create column on a subset of a dataframe, set null on other rows?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I've got a pandas dataframe and I want to calculate percentiles based on the value of the `calc_value` column, unless `calc_value` is null, in which case `percentile` should also be null.

I'm using scipy's [rankdata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) to calculate the percentiles, because it [handles repeated values better than pandas's qcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558936/pandas-calculate-percentile-by-row-and-gracefully-handle-non-unique-values).

However, rankdata has one flaw, which is that it will happily include null values, and there doesn't seem to be an option to exclude them.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'calc_value': [0, 0.081928, 0.94444, None, None]}) 
df['rank_val'] = rankdata(df.calc_value.values, method='min')
df.rank_val = df.rank_val - 1
df['percentile'] = (df.rank_val / float(len(df)-1)) * 100
```

This produces obviously wrong results:

```
   calc_value  rank_val  percentile
0    0.000000         0           0
1    0.081928         1          25
2    0.944440         2          50
3         NaN         3          75
4         NaN         4         100
```

I can calculate the percentiles for all non-null values by slicing the dataframe, and doing the same calculations on the slice:

```
df_without_nan = df[df.calc_value.notnull()]
```

But what I don't know is how to push these values back into the main dataframe as `df['percentile']`, setting `percentile` and `rank_val` to be null on any rows where `calc_value` is also null.

Can anyone advise? I'm looking for the following results:

```
   calc_value  rank_val  percentile
0    0.000000         0           0
1    0.081928         1          25
2    0.944440         2          50
3         NaN         NaN        NaN
4         NaN         NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Are you after: `df.loc[df['calc_value'].notnull(), 'percentile'] = (df.rank_val / float(len(df)-1)) * 100`?

Comment: @EdChum thanks but not quite, because `rank_val` is still not null for the null values of `calc_value` then.

Comment: Ah, try `df.loc[df['calc_value'].notnull(), 'rank_val'] = rankdata(df.calc_value.values, method='min')`

Comment: thanks, tried that a minute ago, but I get `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (5,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,)` - and the same if I try to include only `df.calc_value.not_null().values` inside the `rankdata` expression.

Comment: Hmm, you may need to just set to `NaN` as a post-processing step then `df.loc[df['calc_value'], ['rank_val','percentile']] = NaN`

Comment: ok, I can do the ranks correctly, but then how to get the percentiles? `df.loc[df['calc_value'].notnull(), 'rank_val'] = rankdata(df[df.calc_value.notnull()].calc_value.values, method='min')`

Comment: Got it, thank you for the pointers! `df1 = df[df.rank_val.notnull()]` then `df.loc[df['rank_val'].notnull(), 'percentile'] = (df1.rank_val / float(len(df1)-1)) * 100`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.merge`:

```
df_nonan = df[df['calc_value'].notnull()]
df_nonan['rank_val'] = stats.rankdata(df_nonan.calc_value.values, method='min')
df_nonan['rank_val'] = df_nonan['rank_val'] - 1
df_nonan['percentile'] = (df_nonan.rank_val / float(len(df)-1)) * 100

df_merge = pd.merge(df, df_nonan, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

(This will give a SettingWithCopyWarning; if that's a problem you can do `reset_index` on both dataframes and use the column that generates named `index` instead: `pd.merge(df, df_nonan, on='index', how='left')`, and drop the `index` column after the merge.)  The merged dataframe at this point is

```
    calc_value_x  calc_value_y  rank_val  percentile
0      0.000000      0.000000         0           0
1      0.081928      0.081928         1          25
2      0.944440      0.944440         2          50
3           NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
4           NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
```

Then do a bit of cleanup on the redundant columns:

```
del df_merge['calc_value_x']
df_merge = df_merge.rename(columns = {'calc_value_y' : 'calc_value'})
```

to wind up with

```
    calc_value  rank_val  percentile
0    0.000000         0           0
1    0.081928         1          25
2    0.944440         2          50
3         NaN       NaN         NaN
4         NaN       NaN         NaN
```